# How to add two NSTextAttachment in a label?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add 2 icons in my label. I have 2 images: one is bird and one is duck.

I want my label to show a text like this:

**[Bird Image] Bird [Duck Image] Duck.**

Currently, I just know implement one `NSTextAttachment` in a label.

```
let birdAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
let birdImage = UIImage(named:"bird")
birdAttachment.image = birdImage
let birdString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Bird")
let stringWithBirdImage = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(attachment: birdAttachment))
stringWithBirdImage.appendAttributedString(birdString)

let duckAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
let duckImage = UIImage(named: "duck")
duckAttachment.image = duckImage
let duckString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Duck")
let stringWithDuckImage = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(attachment: duckAttachment))
stringWithDuckImage.appendAttributedString(duckString)
label.attributedText = stringWithBirdImage
```

So how to add 2 `NSTextAttachment` in a label.

Comment: Just append them all to `stringWithDuckImage`.
`stringWithBirdImage.appendAttributedString(stringWithDuckImage)` just before `label.attributedText = stringWithBirdImage` ?

Comment: Thanks. @Larme. It worked.

Comment: @Larme, you should put that in an answer so that you can get credit for it.

Comment: @NRitH: I didn't have time to post it that the author answered it. It's okay, I'm not looking only for reputation and I won't repost "freely" the same answer, and the author cited the source (my comment). The issue was so strange (he already used the `appendAttributedString()`, that I wasn't sure that it was the complete solution).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a small tweak to @Khuong and @Larme's answer for conciseness:

```
func stringForAttachment(named imageName: String, caption: String) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    attachment.image = image
    let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: caption)
    fullString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
    return fullString
}

let labelText = NSMutableAttributedString()
labelText.appendAttributedString(stringForAttachment(named: "bird", caption: "Bird"))
labelText.appendAttributedString(stringForAttachment(named: "duck", caption: "Duck"))
label.attributedText = labelText
```

Comment: That's helpful for me :) +1.

Comment: I don't see any line breaks in your original code, either. Where do you want one, and can you just append a `\n` there?

Comment: This works to display images within UILabel and UITextView, but I can't get it to work for UITextField interestingly

Comment: @vikzilla, that's weird. What does it do instead?

Answer (score 0):

I followed @Larme answer in the comment.

```
let birdAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
let birdImage = UIImage(named:"bird")
birdAttachment.image = birdImage
let birdString = NSAttributedString(string: "Bird")
let stringWithBirdImage = NSAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(attachment: birdAttachment))

let duckAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
let duckImage = UIImage(named: "duck")
duckAttachment.image = duckImage
let duckString = NSAttributedString(string: "Duck")
let stringWithDuckImage = NSAttributedString(attributedString: NSAttributedString(attachment: duckAttachment))

let finalAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
finalAttributedString.appendAttributedString(stringWithBirdImage)
finalAttributedString.appendAttributedString(birdString)
finalAttributedString.appendAttributedString(stringWithDuckImage)
finalAttributedString.appendAttributedString(duckString)
label.attributedText = finalAttributedString
```

It works well.

[image]

Comment: It may be clearer, to do:  `let finalAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: ""); finalAttributedString.appendAttributedString(birdString); finalAttributedString.appendAttributedString(stringWithBirdImage); finalAttributedString.appendAttributedString(duckString); finalAttributedString.appendAttributedString(stringWithDuckImage); label.attributedText = finalAttributedString` 
Also it's useless to have that much "mutable" attributed string, when quite some of them are not mutated.