# Custom images in UITextField like Venmo app

Tags: ios, unicode, uitextfield, uitextview, emoji

I am wondering how Venmo places custom emoticons into their textfield.

When you copy these images and paste them elsewhere, they show up as ":sunset:", ":concert:", etc.

So my guess is the textField delegate checks for any text that matches that pattern (i.e. ":concert:") and replaces it with a tiny image.

So I am wondering how you can place your own little UIImageView within a textField alongside other text.

[image]

Edit: This could also be a UITextView now that I think about it

Comment: Use an `NSAttributedString` and `NSTextAttachment` like they do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38016657/5442445).

Comment: @beyowulf That is helpful - I have it working for UILabel and UITextView, but images won't display in UITextField. I will further explore but this works for now. Thanks!

Comment: @vikzilla That **is** most likely a `UITextView`, since `UITextField` doesn't support rich text.

Comment: @xoudini So you believe the "custom emojis" are rich text? I'm trying to figure out what format the little emoji / images are

Comment: @beyowulf that is one solution, but it is not how Venmo seems to be doing it as demonstrated in my question. Venmos are not images because when you copy them and paste elsewhere, it shows up as text (i.e. ":concert:")

Comment: @vikzilla Well, attributed strings are already basically rich text, but what I meant in this case was 'inline attachments', i.e. images.

Comment: @vikzilla as @xoudini points out you can override the default `copy` implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The text input in the screenshot is almost definitely a custom subclass of `UITextView`, and here I'll present one way to achieve the desired result with just that.

Here's a short demonstration, copying text containing a custom image from one `UITextView` to another:

[image: Demonstration.]

First we'll need to subclass `NSTextAttachment` to have a textual representation of the image at hand, which we'll later use when copying.

```
class TextAttachment: NSTextAttachment {
    var representation: String?
}
```

Now when we create an attributed string containing the image, we'll add the desired textual representation of the image to the attachment:

```
let attachment = TextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "1f197")
attachment.representation = ":anything-here:"
```

Next, we'll subclass `UITextView` and override the `copy(_:)` method declared in [`UIResponderStandardEditActions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponderstandardeditactions) which `UITextView` implements.

```
class TextView: UITextView {
    override func copy(_ sender: Any?) {
        let selectedString = self.attributedText.attributedSubstring(from: self.selectedRange)
        let enumeratableRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: selectedString.length)

        let result = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: selectedString)

        selectedString.enumerateAttribute(NSAttachmentAttributeName, in: enumeratableRange, options: []) { (value, range, _) in
            if let attachment = value as? TextAttachment, let representation = attachment.representation {
                result.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: representation)
            }
        }

        UIPasteboard.general.string = result.string
    }
}
```

We could also override a few other methods, such as `cut(_:)` and `paste(_:)`, but that's outside the scope of the question.

Finally, let's add some attributed text to an instance of the custom text view to see how it performs in action:

```
var textView: TextView // Create an instance however.

let mutableString = NSMutableAttributedString()
mutableString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "Text with "))
mutableString.append(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment))
mutableString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " text attachment."))

self.textView.attributedText = mutableString
```

<sub>Obviously it would be more intuitive to convert text/emoji/whatever into attachments on the fly while the user is typing.</sub>

Comment: Very cool! I did not know you could override the copy / cut / paste methods. I have already implemented the ability to convert text within colons to an image as the user is typing (if an asset of that image name exists) so I will combine your answer with what I have now. Thanks!